# Android PreferenceActivity selections to a file

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I currently have a PreferenceActivity where I have a list of items and checkboxes.

```
public class BevCat extends PreferenceActivity {
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.bev_pref);
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="button_voicemail_category_key"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:title="Juice" >
     <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="appleJuice"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Apple Juice" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="cranberryJuice"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Cranberry Juice" />
      <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="grapeJuice"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Grape Juice" />
       <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="orangeJuice"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Orange Juice" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="v8Splash"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="V8 Splash" />
</PreferenceScreen>


<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="button_voicemail_category_key"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:title="Soft Drinks" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="pepsi"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Pepsi" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="cocaCola"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Coca Cola" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="otherSoda"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Other Soda" />
</PreferenceScreen>


<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="button_voicemail_category_key"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:title="Sports/Energy Drinks" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="gatorade"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Gatorade" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="Powerade"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Powerade" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="energyDrinks"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Energy Drinks" />
</PreferenceScreen>


<PreferenceScreen
    android:key=""
    android:persistent="false"
    android:title="Water" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="water"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Water" />
</PreferenceScreen>


<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="button_voicemail_category_key"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:title="Drink Mixes" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="powdered"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Powdered/Mixes" />
     <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="tea"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Tea" />
</PreferenceScreen>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is a list of categories that once clicked, leads to a list of products and checkboxes.

My ultimate goal is to check off boxes on several lists like this, then have another list that contains only my selections from all of these lists. How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: In a preference activity it will automatically save whether each checkbox is set or not to a shared preference.  Is that good enough?

Comment: How would I implement this?

Like, how would I use the settings saved in the shared preferences to populate a new list?

Comment: You'd open up the SharedPreference file via the SharePreference API and just read the settings in one at a time, checking the value of them.

Comment: when I try:
`SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);`
  
I am not sure what to put in for the string "myPrefs" because I didn't initially create a name for the sharedPreferences file.
  
Also, I think I need to use the getBoolean() method, but I don't understand what use it is because I need to input a String AND Boolean value, but those are what I am wanting. I want to get each item from the list, then if it is marked as true, toString it to a file, and if false, do nothing.

Comment: I don't know if I am missing something obvious, but I have been stuck on this issue for a few days so it is hard to understand some of this after being as confused as me, so sorry about this.

Comment: Use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences to get the preference object